# which data structure stores data in "type:length:value" triplets?

Tags: php

Salam (means Hello) :)

parsing output of a third party script, which was stored in a MySQL database, I encountered data structures almost like JSON, but in a triplets of:

```
key_type:key_length:key_name;
value_type:value_length:value_contents;
```

this is a example of it:

```
a:1:{
    s:5:"title";
    s:28:"<div>This is item title</div>";
    s:9:"permalink";
    s:31:"http://example.com/post-88.aspx";
    s:7:"content";
    s:31:"<div>This is item content</div>";
    s:4:"meta";
    a:1:{
        s:4:"tags";
        s:22:"these, are, some, tags";
    }
}
```

I just want to know is this a common standard structure or something conventional created by this script developers?

Comment: i think those data are [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)
you can use [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to get them into an array

Comment: As mentioned by others this is the serialization format PHP uses. You can read details [here](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/classes_objects/serialization.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) PHP function to parse these. It may suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

`serailize()`. Use `unserialize()` to get variables from it.